# Computing $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-cos(3x)}{5x^2}$ not using derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How can we compute the following limit not using derivative?

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{5x^2}$

I know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0$. But $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{5x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(3x)-1}{3x}\frac{(-3)}{5x^2}=0.-\infty$

Comment: Do you know the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}$ ? It can be found using the Taylor expansion of $\cos$ : $$\cos(x)=1-\frac12x^2+\frac1{4!}x^4+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n)!}x^{2n}+o(x^{2n})$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos3x}{5x^2}\cdot \dfrac{1+\cos3x}{1+\cos3x}$$

$$ = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^23x}{5x^2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{1+\cos3x}$$

$$ = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^23x}{(3x)^2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{9}{5+5\cos3x}$$

$$ = 1\cdot \dfrac{9}{5+5}=\dfrac{9}{10}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\sin^2\left(\frac 32 x \right)=\frac{1-\cos 3x}{2}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^2 ax}{(ax)^2}=1$$